# Does the Z axis of object in world coordinate must be 0 in zhang's calibration method?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

In zhang's calibration method, he says "we assume the model plane is on Z = 0 of the world coordinate system.". Dose this means when we do camera calibration with zhang's method we must put the calibration board on the O-XY plane of the world coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. This assumption just simplyfies calculations.

As you obviously haven't done so, I suggest you read the original publication [A Flexible New Technique for Camera Calibration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.220.534&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

It clearly says:

> The proposed technique only requires the camera to observe a planar
>   pattern shown at a few (at least two) different orientations. The
>   pattern can be printed on a laser printer and attached to a
>   “reasonable” planar surface (e.g., a hard book cover). Either the
>   camera or the planar pattern can be moved by hand. The motion need not
>   be known.

There are also many pictures that show the calibration patterns in various 3d orientations.

Comment: If Z!=0,then H=(r1 r2 r3 t) , it is a 3x4 matrix with 11 unknown variable, one must extract 6 points in each image.
If Z=0, then H=(r1 r2 t), it is a 3x3 matrix with 8 unknown variable, one must extract 4 points in each image.
Is this understanding right?